# In CSS, how to grow the button + button image when the button is focused?

Tags: css

The following code works for the button, but not for the image:

```
button:focus {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    image.width:200px;
}
```

Is there a way to do it in CSS?

Comment: Can you post what your markup looks like? It's not clear to me what you mean by button and button image. What I think you are talking about is how to increase the size of a submit button with its src attribute set to an image. Am I correct?

Comment: @Adam look bobince's answer, it's what I was looking for.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contained image would be part of the selector:

```
button:focus, button:focus img {
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
}
```